# How to find the index of a clicked element from an array with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**How can I find the index of a clicked anchor tag from an array with jquery???**

I want to search if there is an element that eqqal to clicked element, and if is true return the index of that element.

i tried with something like this but it return with -1

```
$('#id').click(function(){

var obj = $('a').get(0).href;
var arr = $.makeArray(obj);
var getclickedhref = $(this).get(0).href;

var clickedindex = $.inArray(getclickedhref, arr);

console.log(clickedindex);
});
```

please can you help me??!

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure what all the `get` and `makeArray` stuff is for but I think you're looking for [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

> Search for a given element from among the matched elements.

So given some anchors:

```
<a>Zero</a>
<a>One</a>
<a>Two</a>
<a>Three</a>
<a>Four</a>
```

you could do things like this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var i = $('a').index(this);
    // i is the index of the clicked anchor within all the anchors.
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/YbUU7/

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
$('a').click(function(){
console.log($(this).index());
})
```

Comment: I just got the same problem and already tried this. It will simply always return `1`.

Comment: +1 jsFiddle works, my personal example not. `$('a').index(this);` works on both sides.